# How can I stub a controller/current_user method in Capybara acceptance test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, capybara

I have a helper method that calls current_user.eligible_for_reward? and I want to stub that call in a Capybara acceptance spec.  In my model I have a placeholder dummy method:

```
User.rb

def eligible_for_reward?
  "blah"
end
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. I tried stubbing current_user, but that results in a "modify frozen object" error because controller is nil.  I believe controller will only be set if I use RSpec's get instead of visit some_path.  I need to stick with visit some_path, I believe, otherwise my page.should ... all fail because page is not set.
2. I tried logging in as user (login_as(user) which successfully runs through the register/login) and then stubbing user.eligible_for_reward?, but that doesn't seem to work, as I'm still getting back the test "blah"

Is there a good way to stub out this method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stubbing in acceptance specs is not a good idea. If there is no other way then you can just do:

```
User.any_instance.stub!(:eligible_for_reward?).and_return(true)
```

Just remember that stubbing/mocking things in acceptance specs means that you really don't test anything.

Comment: I took a different approach.  Agree stubbing wasn't the best here.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that full integration testing is not the only use for Capybara though. It is perfectly reasonable to test Javascript functionality using Capybara/Selenium in Test::Unit, RSpec, or MiniTest, and stub out whatever else you can in Rails to make that run as fast as possible. Also, when stubbing out Devise, I prefer to be more thorough about it, and stub :authenticate_user! to do nothing, and stub the controller's #current_user to return a fake user instance. That way, Devise is completely out of the picture.

Comment: Please note that `stub!` should be replaced with `stub`.  `stub!` is an old and improper alias name for that method.  See last three paragraphs of [this email](http://www.mail-archive.com/rspec-users@rubyforge.org/msg13270.html).

Comment: It's a good rule of thumb, but it's a bit dogmatic to say "you don't test anything".  One place where stubbing in acceptance tests is a good idea is with complex external services.  In these cases you don't want to set up your test context to match the incidentals of a test service.  One approach I've used is to isolate the tests against a complex API using specially formatted factories and test the API thoroughly with lower level suite, and make a thin, easily stubbable shim in my code so surface area of potential errors in acceptance is minimized.